# Stream ArrayBuffer websocket binary.js

Tags: javascript, binary, websocket, arraybuffer

I want so stream a lot of ArrayBuffers.

- Sending Strings from the client to the server and back is no problem!
- Sending ArrayBuffer to the Server is no Problem

Sending an ArrayBuffer from server to client is not working. I get an empty ArrayBuffer on the client => ArrayBuffer{}

Server:

```
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
server.on('connection', function(client){
       client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
       console.log(meta);
            stream.on('data', function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                stream.write(data);
            });
      });  
});
```

the console.log(data) shows me the filled array, so this works.

Client:

```
var wsStream = null;
var client = BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
client.on('open', function(){
    wsStream = client.createStream("audio");

    wsStream.on('data', function(data){
          console.log(data);
    });
});
```

this logs: ArrayBuffer {}

so no data :(

I send the data with: wsStream.write(arrayBuffer);

If i send some array wsStream.write([0,2]); or some string wsStream.write("Hello"); I have no problem and get all my data back.

why is this happening ? thanks :)

Comment: Found a the solution by setting client.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

Comment: Cool - reply to yourself and mark as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by setting binaryType to arraybuffer.

```
var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1");
myWebSocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```